# Xamarin Forms Android - AppCenter push notifications working by device id but not by user id

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm having a problem using Push Notifications with User Ids on Xamarin Forms Android. I have had it working previously but for some reason, now that I have come back to the project I'm having no joy.

On the iOS project everything is working with both device & user id's.

In the app, on a successful login I set the AppCenter UserId from our LoginResponse.

`AppCenter.SetUserId(loginResponse.UserId.ToString());`

To test, I have tried to send pushes through the AppCenter interface and using Postman. The results are as follows.

- All registered devices - Everything is working with this. Multiple device receive the notification.
- Device List - Works fine whether separately or as a group of device id's.
- User List - Nothing is being sent, Results show 0/0.

Using Postman I have sent the following to the API which works perfectly.

```
{
"notification_content": {
   "name": "My Device Test",
   "title": "A New Android Device Message!!",
   "body": "First test in the real app!!"
   },
   "notification_target": {
      "type": "devices_target",
      "devices": [ "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" ]
   },
}
```

But trying to send to a user id, once again, does nothing.

```
{
   "notification_content": {
   "name": "My User Test",
   "title": "A New Android User Message!!",
   "body": "First test in the real app!!"
   },
   "notification_target": {
      "type": "user_ids_target",
      "user_ids": [ "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" ]
   },
}
```

As I said at the start, this has worked fine previously (about 3 months ago) and I've even tried an old build of the app just in case, with no luck.

I'm struggling to think of what I might have missed, so any advice would be great.

Comment: Hi, could you please share the following information :1, The screenshot of the Push configuration page: App->Push->[spanner icon].2,
The link and screenshot of your push details page like below screenshot. (Please copy the link and share with us)   https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN0UR.png

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

After 24 hours of it not working with the user_id, it mysteriously started working across multiple Android devices, along with changing user accounts across devices. I am at a loss at what the cause could have been but happy that it's now testing well across all devices. I'll list the solution as 'A wizard did it'.

Comment: Glad to hear that !  If later other problems also can share here ^.*